# How many objects are eligible for garbage collection in the following question when line 16 is reached

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
3.  class Beta{ } 
4.  class Alpha {
5.    static Beta b1;
6.    Beta b2;
7.  }
8.  public class Tester {
9.    public static void main(String[] args) {
10.     Beta b1 = new Beta(); Beta b2 = new Beta();
11.     Alpha a1 = new Alpha(); Alpha a2 = new Alpha();
12.     a1.b1 = b1;
13.     a1.b2 = b1;
14.     a2.b2 = b2;
15.     a1 = null; b1 = null; b2 = null;
16.     // do stuff
17.   }
18. }
```

I think 2 objects will be available for garbage collection

Comment: "*I think 2 objects will be available for garbage collection*" - This is not correct.

Comment: The only unambiguously correct answer is "it depends".

Comment: @StephenC how so? The rules for eligibility are quite clear.

Comment: The question is whether you are using the theoretical view of eligibility or the practical one.  Q: At line #16 will the runtime *actually* determine that `a2` is no longer reachable?  A: It is implementation dependent.  And it is further confused if you replace the "does stuff" comment with code that  (hypothetically) does stuff with `a2`.

Comment: Why should we care? The garbage collector can determine that a lot better than we can. Or at least a lot better than i can. I’m confident that it will do it’s job, so what more than that do we need to know?

Comment: We shouldn't care.  Unfortunately, there are people out there who like to include questions like this in quizzes ... giving unfortunate students the false impression that they need to know this kind of thing.

Comment: Or even that it is *possible* to know!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the Java implementation ... and how you choose to interpret the question.   In particular what precisely does line 16 mean?

- If we interpret line #16 as the Java compiler would interpret it, it is just a comment.  It does nothing.
- The other interpretation is that line #16 is editorial "short hand" for some *real* Java code that may or may not use the value in `a2`, and may or may not use the value in the (static) variable `Alpha.b1`.

According to the JLS for Java 6 ([12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/execution.html#12.6.1)):

> *"A reachable object is any object that can be accessed **in any potential continuing computation** from any live thread. Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. For example, a compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner."*

So how can we apply that here?

If we treat line #16 as nothing more than a comment, then at that point in the `main` method, the value of `a2` can no longer influence any potentially continuing computation.  But the compiler / optimizer / runtime may not be able to deduce that.  In other words, the actual reachability status of `a2` at line #16 is unclear.

Likewise, unless there is some other code in the application beyond what we have been shown, the value of `Alpha.b1` also won't influence any potentially continuing computation.  Indeed, since that variable is only ever written to, it *could* be optimized away entirely!  But once again, we don't know know for sure whether the compiler / optimizer / runtime could or would deduce that `Alpha.b1` is unreachable, though (IMO) it is much less likely that they would.

And there are a couple of additional factors:

1. If the program is being debugged, that will affect the way the optimizer deals with the code and it may affect reachability.  For example, setting a breakpoint in the `main` method is likely to inhibit any behind-the-scenes nulling of `a2` since the programmer may want to examine the variable.
2. It may not be obvious, but the reachability determination *also* depends on whether or not the `main` method *has been optimized*.  For current generation JVMs that use HotSpot JIT compiler technology, it most likely won't be optimized in the first (and only) call.  But with a AOT compiler, it *might* have been optimized.

Then there is the alternative interpretation of line #16 as a placeholder for some *actual* code.  In that case, all bets are off as far as `Alpha.b1` and `a2` are concerned.  We simply can't answer the question at all unless we know what "stuff" is being done there.

In summary, it is impossible give an unambiguously correct answer on how many objects remain reachable.

---

Note that when the code reaches line #16 (and it is just a comment), reachability is moot anyway.  I can't think of anything that would cause the JVM to need to GC at that point ... or at any time up until the JVM process exits.  (There are no shutdown hooks, and "finalization on exit" is no longer supported.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's give the objects allocated unambiguous names so we don't get confused with the variable and field names.

- The first allocated Beta - betaOne
- The second allocated Beta - betaTwo
- The first allocated Alpha - alphaOne
- The second allocated Alpha - alphaTwo.

In line 12 we assign betaOne to a static variable. This means that unless we clear that static variable, betaOne is not going to be eligible for garbage collection.

In line 14 we assign betaTwo to a non-static variable in alphaTwo. However, when we reach line 16, we do not clear alphaTwo, so its assigned variables are still reachable, so betaTwo is also still reachable.

So betaOne is reachable, and alphaTwo and betaTwo are reachable. Which leaves us onli with alphaOne not reachable.

So the answer is: 1.

Answer (score 0):

An object is eligible for garbage collection if it is unreachable. [JLS, §12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) defines unreachability:

> Every object can be characterized by two attributes: it may be reachable, finalizer-reachable, or unreachable, and it may also be unfinalized, finalizable, or finalized.
>
> A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.
>
> A finalizer-reachable object can be reached from some finalizable object through some chain of references, but not from any live thread.
>
> An unreachable object cannot be reached by either means.

Looking at the program at hand, we see that we create four object initially: `a1`, `a2`, `b1` and `b2` (lines 10 and 11);

We set `a1.b1 = b1;` (line 12). This is a line to fool the unaware: we set the **static** field `Alpha.a1` through an instance reference.

Then, we set `a1.b2 = b1;` (line 13). Notice that we now set the **instance** field `b2` of `a1`.

On line 14, we set `a2.b2 = b2`. Again, notice that we set the **instance** field `b2` of `a2`.

Finally, we `null` all references except `a2`.

For the following analysis, I am going to [assume (`urbandictionary.com`)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Assume) that the comment on line 16 is a placeholder for a computation that accesses all variables that are alive (if we do not make this assumption, then objects that are referenced by unused variables are unreachable as per [JLS, §12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1)).

Now for the analysis of reachability:

- `a2` ist still reachable, so this object is not eligible for garbage collection.
- Through `a2`, we cann still access `a2.b2`, so the object formerly referenceb by local variable `b2` is not eligible
- Through the class `Alpha`, we can still access the object formerly referenced by `b1` (`Alpha.b1`), so this instance is also not eligible
- The only instance that is no longer reachable is the object formerly referenced by `a1`.

Thus, the final answer is: one object is eligible for garbage collection.

We can even observe<sup>1</sup> this behaviour through [`PhantomReference`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html):

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Beta b1 = new Beta();
    Beta b2 = new Beta();
    Alpha a1 = new Alpha();
    Alpha a2 = new Alpha();
    a1.b1 = b1;
    a1.b2 = b1;
    a2.b2 = b2;
    PhantomReference<Alpha> a1Phantom =
        new PhantomReference<>(a1, new ReferenceQueue<>());
    PhantomReference<Alpha> a2Phantom =
        new PhantomReference<>(a2, new ReferenceQueue<>());
    PhantomReference<Beta> b1Phantom =
        new PhantomReference<>(b1, new ReferenceQueue<>());
    PhantomReference<Beta> b2Phantom =
        new PhantomReference<>(b2, new ReferenceQueue<>());
    a1 = null;
    b1 = null;
    b2 = null;
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
    System.out.printf(
        "a1 has %sbeen collected%n", 
        a1Phantom.isEnqueued() ? "" : "not ");
    System.out.printf(
        "a2 has %sbeen collected%n", 
        a2Phantom.isEnqueued() ? "" : "not ");
    System.out.printf(
        "b1 has %sbeen collected%n", 
        b1Phantom.isEnqueued() ? "" : "not ");
    System.out.printf(
        "b2 has %sbeen collected%n", 
        b2Phantom.isEnqueued() ? "" : "not ");
  }
}

class Beta {
}

class Alpha {
  static Beta b1;
  Beta b2;
}
```

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/AFm5tL)

Which prints:

```
a1 has been collected
a2 has not been collected
b1 has not been collected
b2 has not been collected
```

Showing that only `a1` was collected.

---

A note on the code above:

In Java 16+, we would use `a1.refersTo(null)` instead of `a1.isEnqueued()` since method `isEnqueued()` was deprecated, and method `refersTo(T)` has been added.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>: The program relies on the garbage-collector collecting all objects eligible, which is not guaranteed. The garbage collector might not run at all, or it might not collect all eligible objects. This demo is merely meant to illustrate the behaviour, not as definitive proof. For the proof, please read the analysis.</sub>

Comment: The flaw in this analysis is that `a2` cannot be "accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread" ... unless you assume that line #16 *does* access it.  But line #16 is a comment, and "do stuff" is not a clear specification.

Comment: @StephenC The question in and of itself is of course of theoretical nature. If we stopped the program right after line 15 has executed, there is a very clear theoretic definition of reachability. At this point in the program, `a2` is reachable. I do understand that an actual compilation might very well be able to analyze the data flow at compile-time and thus `a2` might no longer be available in the compiled unit or eligible for collection.

Comment: No.  The definition of reachability is premised on what can possibly happen *in the future*.  It doesn't change if you can in a theoretical sense stop time to examine the current state of the variable.  I am quoting directly from (a version of) the JLS.  The same version you quoted from.

Comment: As I said: it is a theoretical question. As such, I [assumed (`urbandictionary.com`)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Assume) that for all reachable variables, there is at least one branch that uses this variable (i.e. "keeps it alive"). I have updated my answer to include this assumption.

Comment: The problem is, even if a variable is subsequently used, that doesn’t imply that the referenced object is considered reachable. In principle, every operation can be optimized to work without the object (e.g. by keeping the required information in CPU registers) or even get eliminated or replaced by something that reproduces a predictable result. The only thing that truly guarantees to prevent the collection of an object, is `Reference.reachabilityFence(…)`—as long as it will affect *observable behavior*. Without finalizers, cleaners, etc, nothing can prevent GC, as you won’t notice anyway.